# Drawing aerial routes for flights on Google Maps API between two markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, markers, aerial-photography

I have been drawing routes until now using DirectionService. However, now my current requirement is to **draw a route on air**.

I did some research and found [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-headings) link which helps us to draw curved polylines between two markers but how do we make sure that this can be the exact flight route between two markers?

What i want to do is something like [this](http://www.flightradar24.com/).

Is there any good example to start with for drawing routes between two airports and animating a flight between the markers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one. Flightradar is a commercial product designed to track aircraft data via ADS-B signals. There is another company on the market, FlightAware, which grants access to its real-time data via an [API](http://flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/). Sadly, it's a commercial product, so if you have no budget, your best chance is to use an existing flight path database.

You can download an airroute shapefile from [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org/data.html) and use its features as the flight path. You have to convert it to KML before, if you use Google Maps API. Sadly, it will be an estimated path, like @Mapperz pointed out, but I guess it's better than a curved line between two points.